# gitlab runner taking long time to give success/fail status

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am running GitLab runner in Kubernetes. The GitLab pipeline job is working fine. Job is taking 10sec to complete the task. but I am getting pipeline status (success/fail) after 5 min.

I tried to set job timeout to 1 min also but it's not working. every time I am getting the status after 5 min.

the same task is working fine in gitlab.com. I am facing this issue in the self-GitLab runner. Please let me know if any setting is required to change in GitLab helm.

GitLab yml
[image]

job duration

[image]

Comment: Does your runner start the jobs quickly? I am wondering if maybe the runner contacting the Gitlab host is somehow slow (e.g. DNS timeout, multiple DNS answers, ...)?

Comment: yes, it's starting fast, within 30-sec the runner spinup and completes its job, but the status is updating after 5 min. every time it's taking the same time between 5-6 min to update the status.